# Ordering arrays of sorted Int

Tags: swift

Is there a short & clean way to compare 2 arrays of sorted `Int` ?

Like `[1,4,7]` should come before `[1,5]` but after `[1,2,3,8]`

A nested for-loop would do it, but I find it cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible implementation (explanations inline, now updated for Swift 3, 4, 5):

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    
    static func <(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> Bool {
        // Compare all elements up to common length, return
        // if a difference is found:
        for (l, r) in zip(lhs, rhs) {
            if l < r { return true }
            if l > r { return false }
        }
        // All common elements are equal, check if rhs is "longer":
        return lhs.count < rhs.count
    }
}
```

Example:

```
print([1,4,7] < [1,5])      // true
print([1,4,7] < [1,2,3,8])  // false
print([1,4,7] < [1,4,7,8])  // true (left array is shorter)
print([1,4,7] < [1,4,7])    // false (arrays are equal)
```

This works with all arrays of comparable elements, not only with integer arrays:

```
print(["a", "B"] < ["c", "D"]) // true
print(["a", "B"] < ["a"])      // false
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know `zip()` !