# How to sort an array of arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

In Ruby you can easily sort arrays of arrays like this:

```
array_of_arrays = [
    [1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1]
]

sorted_arrays = array_of_arrays.sort
 # => [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
# OR
sorted_arrays = array_of_arrays.sort{|a, b| a <=> b}
 # => [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Is there a similarly easy way to do it in Swift?

I have a solution in Swift 2.2 but it involves grabbing the `car` and `cdr` (for Lisp/Scheme folks.. `first` and `rest` for Clojure folks).

If the first elements are equal I pass the remaining elements of each array back into the function until it runs out of elements to test.

It's not too bad, but it involves extending Array to have a function that'll give me its `car` and `cdr` and then the recursive loop which has to be customized based on the contents of the array. I feel like there's got to be a better way, especially in the simple case of an array of arrays of integers as shown above.

I'll post my solution in a couple days if no-one else has anything simpler.

Comment: Just define comparison between two arrays

Comment: This answer looks like a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35599967/2227743

Comment: Is It will be considered as a duplicate?

Comment: thanks for finding the dupe guys.